# jquery specify child and parent

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a problem where my code is not recognizing the parent as "ul" and is instead seeing it as the class. The child has wider effects than I believe it should.

Segments of the code:

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div:last").click(function(){
            $("ul").parent(".northern").children(':nth-child(3)').hide();
            });
        });
    </script>

<section class="northern">
            <h2>US</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Princeton</li>
                <li>Harvard</li>
                <li>Yale</li>

            </ul>
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Click Me!">
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: it works as it should, it hides the button which is the third chilren of northern

http://jsfiddle.net/dTcub/

Comment: If this isn't doing what you expect, I think you don't understand how chaining works in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div:last").click(function () {
        $("ul").closest(".northern").children(':nth-child(3)').hide();
    });
});
```

I think OP want 3rd li item

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dTcub/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div:last").click(function () {
        $(".northern ul").children(':nth-child(3)').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Barmar ty i was on it :)

Comment: This would only make a difference if there were several levels between `.northern` and `ul`. But `.northern` is the immediate parent of `ul`, so they're equivalent.

Comment: @Barmar yeah i think OP want's to remove 3rd li

Comment: I think he also wants to only select the `UL` whose parent is `.northern`.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to think that `$("ul").parent(".northern")` means *find the UL whose parent has class = northern*. What it actually means is *find all ULs, then find all their parents that have class = northern*. `.parent()` is a DOM traversal method, not a filter.

What you presumably want is:

```
$(".northern > ul").children(':nth-child(3)').hide();
```